# How does PHP avoid infinite recursion here?

Tags: php, recursion, getter-setter

Consider this class:

```
class test
{
    public function __set($n, $v)
    {
        echo "__set() called\n";
        $this->other_set($n, $v, true);
    }

    public function other_set($name, $value)
    {
        echo "other_set() called\n";    
        $this->$name = $value;
    }

    public function t()
    {
        $this->t = true;
    }
}
```

I am overloading PHP's magic [`__set()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) method. Whenever I set a property in an object of the `test`  class, it will call `__set()`, which in turn calls `other_set()`.

```
$obj = new test;
$test->prop = 10;

/* prints the following */
__set() called
other_set() called
```

But `other_set()` has the following line `$this->$name = $value`. Shouldn't this result in a call to `__set()`, causing infinite recursion?

I theorized that it would call `__set()` only when setting things outside the class. But if you call the method `t()` you can see it clearly goes through `__set()` too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`__set` is only called once per attempt for a given property name.](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.5.16/Zend/zend_object_handlers.c#L58)  If it (or anything it calls) attempts to set the same property, PHP won't call `__set` again -- it'll just set the property on the object.

Comment: This is correct. If anyone wants to see the implementation details, it's in `zend_object_handlers.c`.

Comment: @Confluence: Thanks...i was wondering where i'd read that.  :)  Couldn't find it in the manual; i was starting to wonder if i'd imagined it.  But all my tests confirmed it, so...

Comment: This answer was SO useful!

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set):

> __set() is run when writing data to **inaccessible** properties

For example:

```
class foo {
  private $attributes;
  public $bar;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->attributes = array();
  }

  public function __set($n, $v) {
    echo "__set() called\n";
    $this->attributes[$n] = $v;
  }
}

$x = new foo;
$x->prop = "value";
$x->attributes = "value";
$x->bar = "hello world";
```

In this case, `$x->prop` is inaccessible and `__set` will be called.  `$x->attributes` is also inaccessible, so `__set` will be called.  However, `$x->bar` is publicly accessible, so `__set` will **not** be called.

Similarly, in the `__set` method, `$this->attribtues` is accessible, so there is no recursion.

In your example code above, `$this->$name` is accessible in the scope in which its called, therefore `__set` is not called.

Comment: What is difference does that make?

Comment: @TZHX Inaccessible can mean not visible OR undeclared. All properties are inaccessible by definition since I have no declared properties.

Comment: @TZHX: The property doesn't *exist* -- it's "inaccessible" til it's set, even within the class.

Comment: In the context in which its called, it is accessible.

Comment: @thetaiko You are wrong. `$this->$name` is *not* accessible until I set the property. It only becomes accessible *after* it's set. You can easily see that if you try to change `$x->prop` after it's been set.

Comment: @Confluence - indeed, you're correct.  But in that case, cHao is right - __set will not call itself again.