# How does PHP detect infinite recursion?

Tags: php, recursion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does PHP avoid infinite recursion here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017741/how-does-php-avoid-infinite-recursion-here)

Someone posted this as a php #wtf in Twitter:

```
class A
{
    private $b;

    function __construct()
    {
        unset($this->b);
    }

    function __get($n)
    {
        echo '!broken!';
        return $this->$n;
    }
}

$a = new A;
$a->b; //EDIT: original question had var_dump($a->b);

//output:
!broken!!broken!
```

My first response to this is that $a->b triggers the __get() for the first echo, then return $this->$n triggers __get again cause $this->b still doesn’t exist, which presumably the code contained in __get() is supposed to handle.  PHP auto-detects the infinite recursion and stops there. This makes sense, but on the other hand PHP only gives an E_NOTICE error for the underfined property A::$b.

So my question is, am I correct that PHP auto-detects the infinite recursion? How could I tell? Or is there some other reason to explain the output given?

Comment: Looks like [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017741/how-does-php-avoid-infinite-recursion-here?rq=1) answers it, i.e. that __set() and __get() will only get called once, and that this fact is not in the manual.  Still would like some confirmation on this though.

Comment: `echo '!broken!';` is echoed when ever the `__get` is called and it is called twice because you unset it, once when its unset and once when its from outside `var_dump($a->b);`

Answer (score 0):

In the class the private variables are not hidden. So, in the execution of the below code you can get the variable $b, without calling __get():

```
class A {
  private $b;
  function get_b()
  {
      return $this->b;    
      }
 }

$a = new A; 
echo $a->get_b();
```

But in below one, you cannot - it will call the function __get():

```
class A 
{
    private $b;
    function get_b()
    {
        return $this->b;    
        }

}

 $a = new A; echo $a->b;
```

So in your example:

> class A {
>       private $b;
>
> ```
> function __construct()
> {
>     unset($this->b);
> }
>
> function __get($n)
> {
>     echo '!broken!';
>     return $this->$n;
> } 
> }
> ```

```
$a = new A; // Here you called unset, and since it doesn't know the "b", it calls __get().
var_dump($a->b); // Again here $a->b is not "exists" or "hidden", so it calls __get() again.
```

In __get(), "return $this->$n" do know the variable $n - that is to say $b (Like in my first code example - the function get_b() ). So it is not actually the infinite recursion, it is just like any other function calling ;)

Comment: Why would `unset` not know about `$this->b`?

Comment: Because unset is a global function. Not a class function. If you're trying to ask that "Why would __construct() do not know about $this->b?", it is because the b in $this->b is not a variable. __get must called to get the private variable $b ;)

Comment: `construct` does know about `$this->b` because `private $b` declared it, and the documentation says "*It is possible to unset even object properties visible in current context.*". If you add some more debug output before/after `new A`, you would see that both calls to `__get` occur after it, during the execution of `var_dump($a->b)`.

Comment: class A
{
    private $b=0;

    function __construct()
    {   
        echo $this->b;
        //unset($this->b);
    }

    function __get($n)
    {   
        echo '!broken!'."\n";
        return $this->$n;
    }
}

$a = new A;

Comment: Sorry, I ran your example with both PHP 5.2 and 5.3, and it didn't trigger `__get` when calling `unset`. I'm not sure I understand what you were trying to show.